# Is it possible to (Unlocked) Package field encryption settings?

Tags: unlocked-package, shield-encryption

I'm having issues proving whether it is or isn't possible to have field encryption settings packaged as part of an Unlocked Package (with a Namespace) and this encryption be enabled automatically upon install. Specifically Deterministic encryption using Shield.

There is no problem creating a package version with both Standard and Custom fields that include the Encryption Scheme in its metadata.

```
Account.Name
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Name</fullName>
    <encryptionScheme>CaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryption</encryptionScheme>
    <trackFeedHistory>true</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
</CustomField>
```

```
Account.CustomField__c
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>CustomField__c</fullName>
    <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
    <encryptionScheme>CaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryption</encryptionScheme>
    <externalId>true</externalId>
    <label>CustomField__c</label>
    <length>30</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>true</unique>
</CustomField>
```

I make sure that the target org has Encryption enabled and Key uploaded for Deterministic Encryption.
[image]
When the package is installed though the fields are *not* set to be encrypted. Retrieving the fields from the Org there is no Encryption Scheme defined on them. Only when I take the same fields that I used to create the package version (add the namespace locally) and deploy them via CLI (so deploy instead of install) the Encryption Scheme is applied to them.

I have found that the Advanced Encryption Setting to encrypt managed fields *is* required in this case. So Managed really means "Namespaced" (not the first time I ran into that). Without this setting even the "deploy" did not add the Encryption.
[image]

I'm struggling to find any documentation that would say that installing encrypted fields should or should not be possible. There is no failure during installation.

UPDATE:
When I take away the Platform Encryption feature setting from the package definition file it still validace and creates a version ok. Sounds like it's not packaging the Encryption Settings (?) or maybe it this is only relevant upon install so it doesn't break validation?

Answer (score 0):

Updated 2024-01-08
I can no longer replicate the scenario where encryption *is* automatically applied to custom fields upon install in unlocked package. Salesforce support also stated that this does not happen. I must have made a mistake somewhere in my testing. Looks like it's not possible at all.

I still haven't found relevant Documentation that says why, but I think I found my answer:

It seems that it's *not* possible to enable Platform Encryption by Unlocked Package (version) install *when* the package has a Namespace.

Now the fun part:

It *is* possible to do this when the Unlocked Package does not have a Namespace. However, *only* if Platform Encryption setting is enabled in the package definition file.

```
{
  ...
  "features": [
        "PlatformEncryption"
    ],
  ...
}
```

If this setting is not present then the Package Version can be created and does not fail. But when it's installed, the field is *not* encrypted.

To be complete, when using a Namespace, the package version is created OK with or without the setting and field is *never* encrypted upon install.